# Building an R package: R CMD build/check vs. R -e "devtools::check()"

Tags: r, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an R package that is stored in an Azure DevOps repo, which has a CI script. Within this script, there are a couple of different ways (that I'm aware of) that I could build/check my package. First, I could run an R session and call `devtools::check` , like so:

```
- script: R -e 'devtools::check(args = "--no-examples")'
  displayName: 'Check package'
```

Alternatively, I could use `R CMD` and break it down into build and check steps:

```
- script: R CMD build .
  displayName: 'Build package'
- script: R CMD check --no-examples *.tar.gz
  displayName: 'Check package'
```

This latter approach builds a .tar.gz file that is then checked, but other than that is there any other practical difference between the two? Specifically, is there any scenario where the results of the checks would differ?